# using a func resign first responder from a array of textviews

Tags: arrays, swift, switch-statement, resignfirstresponder, isuserinteractionenabled

My code uses the didTapAdd func to add a endless amount of textviews to a view controller. The problem is I cant move it because it is a textview. This would work perfectly if it was a label or imageview. Somehow I want to do something like a on off switch everttime didtapadd2 is called i want all of the textviews to not be able to type into so i can move them around and then the func is call again to turn it off.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var addButton = UIButton()
var cutOff = UIButton()
var count: Int = 0
var ht = -90

var arrTextFields = [UITextView]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(addButton);view.addSubview(cutOff)
    cutOff.backgroundColor = .systemPink
    addButton.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
    addButton.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 80, y: view.bounds.midY, width: 50, height: 50)
    cutOff.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 80, y: view.bounds.midY+60, width: 50, height: 50)
    addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapAdd), for: .touchUpInside)
    cutOff.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapAdd2), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func didTapAdd() {


    let subview = UITextView()

    subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    subview.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    arrTextFields.append(subview)
    view.addSubview(subview)
    subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 0, y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(ht), width: 50, height: 30)
    subview.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
    subview.tag = count

    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
    subview.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

    count += 1
    ht += 50

    arrTextFields.append(subview)


}

@objc func didTapAdd2() {


    cutOff.isSelected = !cutOff.isSelected

    arrTextFields.forEach { $0.isScrollEnabled = cutOff.isSelected }


}
@objc func handlePanGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let draggedView = gesture.view!
    view.bringSubviewToFront(draggedView)
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
    draggedView.center = CGPoint(x: draggedView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggedView.center.y + translation.y)
    gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
}
}
```

Comment: You can disable the textView like so: textView.isEnabled = false. Add that at the beginning of your handlePanGesture function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution for your code, I hope this is what you are looking for.

So, first create array of `UITextView` just below `ht` variable as follow:

```
var arrTextFields = [UITextView]()
```

Then inside `didTapAdd` method add subview inside array, so add following line after `ht += 50`

```
arrTextFields.append(subview)
```

Now inside `didTapAdd2` method, write following code

```
@objc func didTapAdd2() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    cutOff.isSelected = !cutOff.isSelected
    arrTextFields.forEach { $0.isScrollEnabled = cutOff.isSelected }
}
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: edited my code with your code. Does not seem to have any effect. Question is updated your with your code above. That is the exact code I used.

Comment: You have missed line. `arrTextFields.append(subview)`

Comment: @maxSmtih, Are you able to move text view by above code ?

Comment: no not able to move it all after calling didtapadd2 and one textfield is still selected.

Comment: See this video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NtkJJF4ttG1SBpj_M8fEw_ihLsvGzBoU, Is it that are you looking for ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203429/discussion-between-sagar-chauhan-and-max-smtih).

Comment: just requested access.